# What can z3' check() do?

Tags: c#, z3

I recently met a C# project that uses z3. I found that when the program runs to check(), it will last for a long long time so that the solution can't get the result.
More specifically, this project has at least 40 constraints and at least 8 variables. The number of constraints and variables are multiples related to the input.
It can be solved only when the input is one, but as long as the input is greater than one, it will be stuck in check(). However, in reality, my input must be greater than one.

I would like to ask what is the use of check(). If there are other methods to replace it, or even if it can be deleted. (I tried to delete it, and the surprising thing is that when the input is greater than one, the result can be obtained quickly.)

Comment: This question doesn't seem related to the Visual Studio application. Are you sure you intended to tag it as `[visual-studio]`?

Comment: @Llama The project is run on visual studio.

Comment: Please review the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) to see if this tag is correct for your question: _"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."_

Comment: Examples of times when the `[visual-studio]` tag might be appropriate: Your question is about an extension for Visual Studio that you're creating, you're asking how to do something in Visual Studio (e.g. "how do I add a new class to a project?"), you're having some problem with Visual Studio (e.g. "I can't create a .NET Core project in VS."). Examples where it isn't appropriate: "my code (written in C#) doesn't compile because of an error", "what is the difference between int and Int32 in C#?", "my application is crashing on this line of code," etc.

Comment: visual-studio tag is a red-herring indeed. I'm removing it.

Comment: I'm so sorry for not reading the request carefully. This is the first time I use this community, there are still many places I need to learn. Thanks for your correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `check` makes sure the constraints given are satisfiable. If you don't call check, then obviously `z3` will not check anything for you, so it isn't surprising that it goes faster.

Regarding if you can delete the call to `check`; well, you haven't told us what this project is, nor what it uses z3 for. But in general, no; you cannot remove the call to `check`. It'll return `sat` or `unsat` as a result (of course, it can also fail to terminate or return `unknown` depending on what constraints are asserted.) And you'd proceed according to the result of the call.

I'd advise looking at how your code uses the result of the call to check. Or contact the developer in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will study further based on your suggestions.